# How do i do i make a flickering light?

Tags: flicker

Okay so in roblox i have been trying to make a flickering light but it doesn't seem work. So i have tried finding what my error in line one is but.. it doesn't seem to work and i can't seem to find it.

```
while true do
    math.randomseed(tick())
    local Brightness = math.random(0.1 , 1)
    local Light = script.Parent
    local SpotLight = Light.SL
    local RandomPause = (math.random(0.5 , 5))
    wait(RandomPause)
    SpotLight.Brightness = Brightness
    wait (RandomPause)
    SpotLight.Brightness = Brightness
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a spotlight into the part
2. Insert this script into the part:

   ```
   local spotlight = game.Workspace.Light.SpotLight

   while true do 
   spotLight.Enabled = true
   wait(2)
   spotLight.Enabled = false
   wait(0.1)
   spotLight.Enabled = true
   wait(0.3)
   spotLight.Enabled = false
   wait(0.5)

   end
   ```

You can edit the "wait(time)" as you wish to speed up the flickering or slow it down.